# MS Access Multiple language support for forms only

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there any way to apply another language to Access forms. I have an issue while creating forms, as the DB values are stored in English and I have to generate two identical forms from same Table in different languages. Everything goes well till I reach a look up field like Gender. My table optional values are 'Male' and 'Female' and is good for English form but How can I change that in my non-English form without changing table value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to store the actual values in the main table as `M` and `F`, e.g.

```
ID  FirstName  Gender
--  ---------  ------
 1  Gord       M     
 2  Angie      F
```

and create a reference table named [Genders] like so:

```
TableValue  Language  Translation
----------  --------  -----------
M           fr_ca     masculin   
F           fr_ca     féminin    
M           en_us     Guy        
F           en_us     Girl       
M           en_ca     Male       
F           en_ca     Female
```

On your form, create a hidden unbound text box named `txtFormLanguage`, and in the Form_Load event handler populate it like this:

```vbs
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.txtFormLanguage = IIf(IsNull(Me.OpenArgs), "en_ca", Me.OpenArgs)
End Sub
```

Now your combo box can use the following as its `Row Source`...

```sql
SELECT TableValue, Translation FROM Genders WHERE (((Genders.Language)=[txtFormLanguage]));
```

...and have other properties similar to the following:

Bound Column: 1
Column Count: 2
Column Widths: 0";1"

When the form is opened normally (without `OpenArgs`)...

```vbs
Docmd.OpenForm "ClientForm", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
```

...it defaults to `en_ca` (English, Canada) and the combo box displays

```
Male
Female
```

When the form is opened for `fr_ca` (French, Canada)...

```vbs
Docmd.OpenForm "ClientForm", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal, "fr_ca"
```

...the combo box displays

```
masculin
féminin
```